# Django view variable not presenting any data in html

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to pass "Hello World!" from a Django view into index.html

view.py (excuse the brevity):

```
def index(request):
    context = "Hello World!"
    return render(request, 'hud/index.html', {"context": context})
```

index.html (brevity):

```
<html>
    <h1>{{ index.context }}</h1>
</html>
```

I am expecting it to print the value of "context" and it does not. I do not get any errors, just a blank screen. In the chrome page source, I see:

```
<html>
    <h1></h1>
</html>
```

Any  help is appreciated I am new!

Comment: return of index must be in function. it seem it's out with this indent.

Comment: That was a typo. I have corrected it and still same result.

Comment: I am missing something fundamental to Django views...

Comment: did you tried {{ context }} instead of {{ index.context }}

Comment: That was it! Can you explain why? Also provide your answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try like this ?

in python:

```
def index(request):
    context = "Temp = {0} *C".format(sensor.read_temperature)
    return render(request, 'hud/index.html', {"context": context})
```

in template:

```
<h1>{{ context }}</h1>
```

you should send variables with dictionaries {"context": context} is our dictionary. In Django templates, data passed by key, so we can get it with {{ context }}. You have to pass an object to get with doted (index.context) syntax.